# Creating an Edge and Node list from proportional OTU table in r

Tags: r, igraph, analysis

I have made proportional OTU tables from bacterial OTU counts and algal OTU counts and I have selected the top 50 taxa present from both data-frames. I then merged the data frames together using

`inner-join()`

My files are set up so taxa are column names (abbreviated to B1-B50 for bacteria and D1-50 for algae), and my sample locations are row names.

I am just wondering how to create an edge and node list from this dataset, please? I want to create a network analysis and all online examples seem to already have done the edge and nodes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You are using a lot of terminology which most people here may not be familiar with (e.g., "OTU"). If people don't understand your post, they will not answer.

Comment: I'm familiar with the OTU terminology, but you need to decide how to create the relationship first, and then your relationship between the OTUs is the edge. Most networks refer to some sort of microbial interaction. - please read this post for more information: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/90107/identifying-otu-interactions-hubs/92566#92566